# Select column_name from cols return nothing although column exists

Tags: sql, oracle, data-dictionary

i am trying to execute this statement in Oracle 9i.  However it seems that the result set is empty although J am very sure that there are many columns with the name ID.

```
select * from cols where column_name like '%ID%';
```

Also, the following statement returns an empty result set.

```
select * from cols;
```

May I ask if this could be due to user privilege?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Oracle Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2134.htm#sthref1352) says of COLS:

> ```
> "COLS is a synonym for USER_TAB_COLUMNS."
> ```

This suggests a simple answer to your conundrum: you are connected to the database through a user which owns no tables (or views).  Either change your user or try selecting from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS (which shows results from all the tables/views you have privileges on).

Comment: I think somewhere along the line before your post a member mentioned that this could also be affected by a feature called the Virtual Private Database that is since version Oracle 8i, however i think the post has been removed, APC would you have any comments on this? Kindly. :)

Comment: @ChinBoon - Virtual Private Database (AKA Fine-Grained Access Control) is a mechanism for invisibly restricting access to rows of data - and columns after 10gR2 - by defining additional filters which are applied to all DML statements.  Check out DBMS_RLS to find out more.  I don't think it is relevant to your situation, because VPD would not be applied to the data dictionary.